# Windows media center and network / internet music

Tags: lan, windows-media-center

When I want to play LAN music or stream, no amount of looking in the GUI shows anything more than "radio tuner" integration, and I don't care about FM radio.

1. How can Windows Media Center be used to play .PLS URLs ?

   How can I use Windows Media Center to play MP3s that are in my LAN?

I have little understanding of Windows Media Center's differences to Windows Media Player, and normally use the latter. I would prefer the former because it has a neat interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LAN access, in Media Centre:

1. Scroll down to bottom and select "Tasks"
2. Select "Settings"
3. Select "Media Libraries", then "Music" (for mp3's)
4. Select "Add folders to library"
5. Then choose depending on your configuration (i.e. mapped network drive, manually add share)

Comment: Thanks for your easy solution. I'll have to ask about question 1 separately... WMC looks more like a DVD player rather than its network-friendly sibling, WMP.